# Paste clipboard text to a website

Tags: vb.net

Website address:
http://translate.naver.com/#/ja/ko

I'm trying to paste clipboard text to website's textbox.

```
Web1.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = True
                Web1.Navigate("http://translate.naver.com/#/ja/ko")
                WaitForPageLoad()
dim Otext as string = Clipboard.GetText
Dim htmlDoc = Web1.Document
Dim elem_Input As HtmlElement = htmlDoc.GetElementById("transEditorText")
elem_Input.SetAttribute("value", Otext) 
Dim elem_Input_Submit As HtmlElement = htmlDoc.GetElementById("startTranslateBtn")
                elem_Input_Submit.InvokeMember("click")
```

Above code worked until few days ago.
But then they changed something and code isn't working anymore.
Is there any other way to paste text to that textbox, so I can get it auto translated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like they changed the html code.
This should work:

```
Web1.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = True
Web1.Navigate("http://translate.naver.com/#/ja/ko")
WaitForPageLoad()
dim Otext as string = Clipboard.GetText
Dim htmlDoc = Web1.Document
Dim elem_Input As HtmlElement = htmlDoc.GetElementById("transEditorText")
elem_Input.InnerText = Otext
Dim elem_Input_Submit As HtmlElement = htmlDoc.GetElementById("startTranslateBtn")
elem_Input_Submit.InvokeMember("click")
```

I didn't test this code. I used my firefox developer console and javascript:

```
document.getElementById("transEditorText").innerText = "hello world"
document.getElementById("startTranslateBtn").click()
```

Comment: You mean `htmlDoc.GetElementById("transEditorText")` instead of `htmlDoc.GetElementById("textarea_for_autocomplete")`; i test it with VB.Net it work.

Comment: Thanks. I tried to fix it for hours but I couldn't. Replacing elem_Input.SetAttribute by elem_Input.InnerText in your solution, solved it instantly.